# How to snap Animated.View to a point in the screen using PanGestureHandler in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

[image]

Here, I would want to wrap the circle with a `PanGestureHandler`, make it draggable and snap to the X mark if it goes near it.

The part that confuses me is when dragging I'm using the `translationX` and `translationY` values to move the circle around which means it will always start at (0,0). How do we find the `translateX` and `translateY` values of the X mark for the circle? i.e. what `translateX` and `translateY` of circle will make it snap to the X value - how do we find this? I have the `absoluteX` and `absoluteY` values for X mark and the circle but unsure how to translate the absolute values to the translation values.

Am I over complicating this? Is there an easy way to go about this?

Comment: Are you looking for a function that will tell you if the snap point is within a certain distance of the circle? Or just how to get the absolute values of the circle after translation?

Comment: @Abe To be honest, I am not really sure how this is implemented. The objective here is that you can drag the circle and if the circle is withing +10 radius of the X mark, then it snaps to the center of the X mark.

Comment: Here's an easy solution with a rectangle. You can find good circle testing algorithms in geospatial applications. `if (Math.abs(currentX - targetX) < 10 && Math.abs(currentY - targetY) < 10) { // give x and y offset withTiming animations }`

Comment: Hmm Im still not sure how this is implemented - could you please provide a very minimal example. It can be just on click of circle -> it animated to the X mark (no drag needed).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this example code to your project, after that some thing may be clarify for you how does it work. 10-20min some tests and gaming with example and you can to run your application as need for you project

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedGestureHandler,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withSpring,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';

import {
  GestureHandlerRootView,
  PanGestureHandler,
  PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const SIZE = 100.0;
const CIRCLE_RADIUS = SIZE * 2;

type ContextType = {
  translateX: number;
  translateY: number;
};

export default function App() {
  const translateX = useSharedValue(0);
  const translateY = useSharedValue(0);

  const panGestureEvent = useAnimatedGestureHandler<
    PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent,
    ContextType
  >({
    onStart: (event, context) => {
      context.translateX = translateX.value;
      context.translateY = translateY.value;
    },
    onActive: (event, context) => {
      translateX.value = event.translationX + context.translateX;
      translateY.value = event.translationY + context.translateY;
    },
    onEnd: () => {
      const distance = Math.sqrt(translateX.value ** 2 + translateY.value ** 2);

      if (distance < CIRCLE_RADIUS + SIZE / 2) {
        translateX.value = withSpring(0);
        translateY.value = withSpring(0);
      }
    },
  });

  const rStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [
        {
          translateX: translateX.value,
        },
        {
          translateY: translateY.value,
        },
      ],
    };
  });

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.circle}>
          <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={panGestureEvent}>
            <Animated.View style={[styles.square, rStyle]} />
          </PanGestureHandler>
        </View>
      </View>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  square: {
    width: SIZE,
    height: SIZE,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 256, 0.5)',
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  circle: {
    width: CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2,
    height: CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: CIRCLE_RADIUS,
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 256, 0.5)',
  },
});
```

I hope its help you.

Comment: Thank for you for this, but this is not what I am looking for. I'm looking something specific to this case - where the circle snaps to a point on the screen. Here, I believe there isn't a snap logic but only this - if distance covered by circle is > or < something, do something.

Comment: You can use <View onLayout={event => {}} />  for get size and coordinates you own View, after that u can pass these properties to your Circle for bind these values/coordinates

Comment: Okay, but I would be getting the absolute values right? How would I convert the absolute values of the X mark to the translation values of the circle?

Comment: You need to get coordinates X-mark and get coordinates Circle , using onLayout() callback, after that move Circle to X mark coordinates, maybe you will need position: 'absolute' style for Circle

Comment: I'm unsure of how to implement this - can you please give me an example code when free?